# Saving a Postman collection variable from the response body

Tags: javascript, request, postman

Trying to figure out why I cannot get this to work? Also, console does not give much of a result.

**Scenario:**

1. Making the POST request to get the response with TOKEN
2. Save the response token to collection variable (as the collection file will be used for importing to another testing solution in the cloud)
3. Using that collection variable to log out from the session

So, I need to be able to store this as a collection variable and use that token when logging out from the session/DELETE the API admin session.

**Error in the console:**

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError: Unexpected token 'o' at 1:2 [object Object] ^

**Tests:**

```
var response = pm.response.json()
var jsonData = JSON.parse(response)
pm.collectionVariables.set("token", jsonData.response.token);
```

**Response body:**

```json
{
    "response": {
        "token": "***"
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "text": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You don't need this line `var jsonData = JSON.parse(response)` as the first line is parsed already. Then update the reference to the value to the correct variable name.

Comment: Alright. This did help. :) Thanks, and I would suggest you to make this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JSON.parse(responseBody) always gets a json representation of the response.

A complete fail safe approach would be:

```
pm.test("response is ok",  ()=>{
    pm.response.to.have.status(200)
})

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.token);
```

Comment: @x0nomad hope this answer helps

Comment: Thanks! This is a better, of course. Tested, works. ;)

Comment: Please don't use that code, it's using the older variable set and parsing syntax. You had the correct code, you just didn't need to parse it again.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(pm.response.code == 200){
    pm.environment.set("variable_name",pm.response.json().field_name)
}
```

variable_name is the name of the variable setup in the Environment and field_name is the name of the field or property in the response from a GET, POST or any method.

Comment: where can I put this code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach i used.

1. Send the request
2. Check if there response is 200
3. If it's true set the token

```js
pm.test("response is ok",  ()=>{
   if( pm.response.to.have.status(200)){
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.token);
}
})
```

You need to change your status code depending on the condition.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `pm` to `postman` because `pm` is newer and `postman` may be deprecate.

a test code using `pm`:

```js
pm.test("Save the new token to environment", function () {
    var data = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set('token', data.token);
});
```

---

A complete test script could look like this:

```js
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test("Response has required items", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.be.an('object').that.has.all.keys('response', 'message', 'token');
});

pm.test("Save the new token to environment", function () {
    var data = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set('token', data.token);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in the `Tests` section which is right next to `Pre-request Script`.

```
pm.test("save environment variable", ()=> {    
    pm.response.to.have.status(200)    
    var response = pm.response.json()  
    pm.environment.set("variableName", response.key1.key2);  
})
```